# How to register correctly a custom build Tensorflow Op under Python and Windows?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am succesfully building Tensorflow with GPU support (r1.3) under Windows with the cmake setup provided from Tensorflow.

I added a custom op as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/extend/adding_an_op) and used the guidelines [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1103) to add the custom op to the cmake setup with AddUserOps.

When I try to load the custom op dll with tf.load_op_library(...) and print the result it says `<module '7b088d8b906b36d3e50721b0adbaaa6a'>` so the DLL seems to load correctly. When I use the LoadLibrary() call from Windows itself within C++ there are also no errors reported.

Still I can't use the DLL in Python. When I register the Op as "ExampleOp" python finds no function "module.example_op()".

How can I use the registered Op with the Python API to build Graph Definitions with it? It seems I am missing a piece somewhere along the line?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I am also trying to resolve this problem.